# How do I hide an overflowing Highcharts treemap datalabel?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, treemap

I want to configure a Highcharts treemap so that if the datalabel is long enough to overflow the *point bounds* (as opposed to just the chart bounds), it is hidden.

An example of the problem can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/atootspb/

I would like the final label ("Gggggg") not to display since it overflows its point's boundaries. I have tried experimenting with the `dataLabels` options including `padding`, `overflow` and `crop`, all to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done just by configuring predefined chart options.

Here's a custom code that'll do the job:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var points = this.series[0].points;
        points.forEach(function(point) {
          console.log(point);
          if(point.shapeArgs.width < point.dataLabel.width) {
            point.dataLabel.hide();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y75whsjr/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for. It seems quite similar to [this line](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/modules/treemap.src.js#L1134) in the Highcharts source, where the data label's width is set to that of the point (but it doesn't seem to have any effect for me) - maybe this is the intended behaviour and is a bug?

Comment: It seems to be a bug. It only happens when the word is wider than its point. Everything looks fine if you insert a white space in the middle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pmmprqqp/ Another issue occurs when `useHTML` is enabled: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dg5yw83s/ - the label is not aligned properly.

Comment: I reported two issues regarding this topic: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8159 and https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8160

Comment: Thanks, subscribed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`overflow`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.overflow) option for DataLabels.

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/ukfs5qo6/

Or, a more dynamic approach:

You have full control on the labels with the `formatter` option.

To specifically get if the label is overflowing the content is a bit hard to do, but you can get the `width` of the content and make some calculation on how much pixels the text would have and then decide to show or not the label. You can even show only part of the label if it doesnt fill the whole thing.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7jdedzy0/
In this example, I am showing labels only of points which value represents more than 5% of the whole map.

Hope it helps,
regards

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach but unfortunately doesn't solve the issue I have where the labels could be of arbitrary length - for example, even a >50% point could have a label that is too long to fit in the point's bounds.

Comment: Hi @BenElliott! Yesterday I have run into the right way of doing it. There is an `overflow` option on `DataLabels`. I edited my answer. Please check it :)

Comment: Thanks, but actually `overflow: 'crop'` only seems to ensure that the label doesn't overflow the _chart_ as opposed to the _point_. You can see this in your example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2y0vdbq7/1/).