# Don't show data label if not enough room

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart using Highcharts.

I also want to display data labels in the bars, but I only want to display the labels if the bars are long enough to contain them. If the text is longer than the bar, I want to hide the text

Here is an example of the chart I am trying to build:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function(){
                    return 'text for value '+this.point.y;
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    },{
        data: [12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
    }]
});
```

And here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/xyszd7p4/

How can I hide the data points if they are too long? In my example, I want to hide the "text for value 1" data label because it does not fit inside the bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer shows one way of hiding labels that are too long: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49750334. That does not work directly for a bar chart (or for multiple series). But by editing it a little, like this:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      this.series.forEach(function(series) {
        var points = series.points
        points.forEach(function(point) {
          console.log(point);
          if (point.shapeArgs.height < point.dataLabel.width) { //using shapeArgs.height since this is a bar chart (would be width otherwise)
            point.dataLabel.hide();
          }
        });
      });

    }
  },
  type: 'bar'
},
```

You can acheive what you are after.

**Working JSFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/87c2t4uy/